# rails check if url ends with number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

I am trying to create a `redirect_to :back` that is triggered after a person object is deleted.  There are several pages a user can come from before triggering the delete object code.  If they come from the `person#show` page, i want to redirect to a route called `admin_persons_path`.  If they come from any other page, I just want the user to be redirected back to the page they are on.  The persons#show page has a url structure of `localhost:3000/admin/persons/[some_id_number]` .  I am trying to write code that reads the referrer url and redirects accordingly.  I am trying to do something like:

```
if request.referer.end_with?(some regular expression)
    redirect_to :back
else
    redirect_to admin_persons_path
end
```

The problem is that I dont think the end_with? method can accept a regular expression because when I try it with a regex i get the error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into String
```

How do I get this to work?

Please note using `redirect_back(fallback_location: admin_persons_path)` won't work because the referrer technically exists.  If there is a built-in method that accomplishes what I want, I am unaware of it.

Comment: You could split the url by '/' and check if the last parameter is a number or not.

Comment: Use something like `if request.referer =~ /regex\z/` (or if the regex is a variable, `/#{regex}\z/`)

Comment: The problem may be as simple as your formatting ... I can't tell from your example, but a regex is just a regex. But something like regex.match(url) returns a string.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to do the regex - everything ive tried so far fails.  returning a string doesn't help though.  id imagine id need to return a true or false for a match.

Comment: is something unclear about the question?  i basically need to know how to check a url for ending with a number? im surprised there arent a ton of answers.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example

url = "http://www.example.com/articles?page=2"

```
def last_element_for_url(url)
  if /[0-9]/.match(a[a.length-1]).to_a.length > 0
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

For rails, we can set  `url = request.original_url` , then the above method will return true or false depending on the url.